# In java trying to extract XMLNS using a Regexpression

Tags: java, regex, xml, string, xml-namespaces

I have been trying for a few hours to get this right, and I really can't seem to do it...

Given a string

```
"xmlns:oai-identifier=\"http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier\""
```

what is the correct expression to "save" the `http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier` bit?

Thanks in advance, really having trouble getting this right.

```
String validXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed "
            + "xmlns:oai-identifier=\"http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier\" "
            + "xmlns:mingo-identifier=\"http://www.google.com\" "
            + "xmlns:abeve-identifier=\"http://www.news.ycombinator.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier\">"
            + "</feed>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(validXML);
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Is not printing out anything. Be aware that this attempt was just to get the string inside the quotes, I was going to worry about the other part once I got that working... To bad I never got that working. Thanks

Comment: "*really having trouble getting this right*" can we see your attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: Sure my attempts, where just to extract the stuff in the quotes, was going to worry about the xmlns after I figured that out.

Thanks for formatting my post, long time lurker, 2nd time poster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expressions are so expensive - don't use them when you don't need to!! There are a million other ways to parse a string.

```
String validXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed "
        + "xmlns:oai-identifier=\"http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier\" "
        + "xmlns:mingo-identifier=\"http://www.google.com\" "
        + "xmlns:abeve-identifier=\"http://www.news.ycombinator.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier\">"
        + "</feed>";
String start = "xmlns:oai-identifier=\"";
String end = "\" ";
int location = validXml.indexOf(start);
String result;
if (location > 0) {
    result = validXml.substring(location + start.length(), validXml.length());
    int endIndex = result.indexOf(end);
    if (endIndex > 0) {
        result = result.substring(0, endIndex);
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Could not find end!");
    }


}
else {
    throw new Exception("Could not find start!");
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: ended up using ArrayList<Object> namespaces = new ArrayList<Object>();
  String[] splits = xml.split("xmlns");
  for(int s = 1; s < splits.length; s++)
  {
   namespaces.add(splits[s].split("\"")[1]);

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be that the first `.*` in your regular expression is too eager and matching more characters than you'd like.

Try changing `".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*"` to be `"xmlns.*=\"(.*)\".*"` and see whether that works.

If it doesn't work at first, you can also try re-instating the quote escaping.  Off the top of my head, I *think* you don't need them escaping, but I'm not 100% sure.

Note also that this will only match a single namespace declaration, not each one in the `validXML` variable in your example.  You'll have to split the string in order to use this on an arbitrary number of `xmlns:.*=` attributes.

Comment: okay I have the string split into a String[] object that contains 3 elements...

:oai-identifier="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier" 


:mingo-identifier="http://www.google.com" 


:abeve-identifier="http://www.news.ycombinator.org/OAI/2.0/oai-identifier"></feed>

Now I want to just get the stuff in between the "" and add that info into an array, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can loop through the array to do this.  However, if you're considering doing much more XML parsing in addition to this then you should consider the approach outlined in @helderdaroch's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are reading XML, you might be using DOM, so you can extract the namespace from the prefix name using `lookupNamespaceURI()` once you parse the document with the `setNamespaceAware()` option set to `true`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(validXML)));

String namespace = doc.lookupNamespaceURI("oai-identifier");
```

It's simpler and you don't have to do any string parsing.

Comment: This is definitely a better approach than using bespoke regular expressions.